# Can i download new Background Images when updating a LiveTile via Push Notification?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, live-tile

While working on my Windows Phone i came across a problem with updating my live-tiles: in order to update them more than once every hour i need to send a push notification. Can someone with experience tell me wether the following is possible:

Wether the App itself is running or not, once every half hour my server will send a push notification to all phones with the app installed. Then the following is supposed to happen:

- Download a background image for the normal livetile's back background
- Download a different image for the double sized livetile back background
- Generate a new background for the front of the normal sized livetile using UI-Elements
- Generate a new background for the front of the double sized livetile using UI-Elements

as far as i understand i can run pretty much whatever code i want when receiving the push notification or are there any restrictions i might have missed?

thx for your time and greetings from germany,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 30 Minutes +/- 10 Minutes are good enough for you, you could use a [scheduled background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). There you can set/download a new tile image every 30 minutes, as long as you update your tile it will also not have to be re-registered every two weeks.